# I need help pasting formula and values to an existing script

Tags: copy, formula, paste

I am hoping someone could make this script copy and paste formulas (not just values) from B3:B
&
Clear the values but not the formulas from B3:B?

(B3:B below is a mixture of formulas and values). Thank you in advance. I hope to get good at scripts and help others as well.

Here is the script that works perfect for everything else I want it to do

```
function onEdit(e) {
const sh = e.range.getSheet(); 
if(sh.getName() == 'Schedule Condensed' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 14 &&              //  e.value          == "TRUE") 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule Condensed');
var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Ready List');
var lr = sh2.getLastRow()+1;
var gv2 = sh1.getRange('B3:B').getValues();

var result1 = [...gv2.flat()];


var results = [result1];
sh2.getRange(lr,1,results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);

var range = SpreadsheetApp
.getActive()
.getSheetByName("Schedule Condensed")
.getRange(4,2,11);
 range.clearContent();
}
```

I am very new to scripts and have tried to get this for at least 15 hrs just getting the script to work as well as it does. Just hoping to get the last bit of info?